# Python, run commands in specific order

Tags: python, unit-testing, file-io

I'm writing a script that gets the most recently modified file from a unix directory.
I'm certain it works, but I have to create a unittest to prove it.

The problem is the setUp function. I want to be able to predict the order the files are created in.

```
self.filenames = ["test1.txt", "test2.txt", "test3.txt", "filename.txt", "test4"]
newest = ''
for fn in self.filenames:
    if pattern.match(fn): newest = fn
    with open(fn, "w") as f: f.write("some text")
```

The pattern is "test.*.txt" so it just matches the first three in the list. In multiple tests, newest sometimes returns 'test3.txt' and sometimes 'test1.txt'.

Comment: That doesn't look like a unit test to me. Unit testing wouldn't involve actually writing files to the disk...

Comment: The way you phrased the question is a little vague. The `newest` variable in this code will always refer to the last item in the list `self.filenames`. Or is this a question about the behavior of your script that moves the most recently modified file?

Comment: You're trying to write some kind of integration test here, rather than a [unit test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `os.utime` to explicitly set modified time on the files that you have created. That way your test will run faster.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that the filesystem you are using supports fractional seconds on file create time.

I suggest you insert a call to `time.sleep(1)` in your loop so that the filesystem actually has a different timestamp on each created file.

Comment: thanks. You are right. I didn't even think about the filesystem giving them the same timestamp.

Comment: I love the answer by @Lance-Helsten, as it will not hold up your script for a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to syncing. Just because you call write() on files in a certain order, it doesn't mean the data will be updated by the OS in that order.

Try calling [f.flush()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush) followed by [os.fsync()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fsync) on your file object before going to the next file. Giving some time between calls (using sleep()) might help also